# how to disable alerts from google maps API V3

Tags: android, cordova, blackberry-10

I am using google maps api version 3 in my phonegap application. Is there any way to disable javascript alerts from it ?

Or Any way to disable alerts in the overall application?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. What alerts are happening? From what I understand, you subscribe to alerts via event listeners. What action causes an alert box to pop up?

Comment: "access to "www.address1.com" are not allowed" this is the alert I am getting. @Dom

Comment: What do you do that causes that alert to come up? It comes up when you click on the map? It comes up when you try to look up an address?